# What does this syntax with brackets only mean?

Tags: objective-c

I was surprised to see in a objective-c project, the following line codes

```
- (void)methodName
{
    ... some code...

    {
        ... some code
    }

    {
        ... some code
    }

}
```

What does the inner brackets stand for ? They seems not be preceded by any statement.
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The brackets create a new scope. Variables defined within the scope will not persist after the end of the scope. I personally use this to separate out bits of logic to make things easier to read.

**Example 1**

This example demonstrates the lack of access to variables instantiated inside of a more narrowly defined scope.

```
-(void)blockTestA {
    int j = 25;

    {
        int k = 5;

        // You can access both variables 'j' and 'k' inside this block.
    }

    // You can only access the variable 'j' here.
}
```

**Example 2**

This example demonstrates how creating a new block scope allows us to have different variables with the same name. You can read more about scope [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Variable_Scope_and_Storage_Class).

```
-(void)blockTestB {
    int j = 25;

    {
        int j = 5;
        NSLog(@"j inside block is: %i", j); // Prints '5'
    }

    NSLog(@"j outside of block is: %i", j); // Prints '25'
}
```

Comment: Good to know, since i've wondered at such code - but what is the convention for using these - is there any case in which they'd really be needed, and are they common in objective-c or a throwback to C?

Comment: There isn't a convention for using these. It's kind of like the `switch ... case` and `if ... else` statements. They both work fairly similarly, so it's usually just a matter of personal preference. They are necessary in several very normal instances, you just may not think of them in this way. (Examples: defining the implementation of a new selector, defining blocks, `try ... catch` blocks) Almost all other uses are semi-optional (i.e. you could implement a `for` loop with or without, but only if the immediately contained logic is a single line.) Creating a new block scope is supported by C.

Answer (score 3):

They create a block scope. Declared variables inside those blocks will not be available outside the blocks.

Answer (score 3):

The inner brackets limit the scope of variables declared inside of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)methodName
{
    ... some code...

    {
      int i;//the scope of i is within this block only
        ... some code
    }

    {
       int i;//the scope of i is within this block only
       ... some code
    }

}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.